# Node.js: Gzip compression?

Tags: compression, gzip, node.js

Am I wrong in finding that Node.js does no gzip compression and there are no modules out there to perform gzip compression? How can anyone use a web server that has no compression? What am I missing here? Should I try to—gasp—port the algorithm to JavaScript for server-side use?

Answer (score 84):

Node v0.6.x has a stable [zlib module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html#zlib) in core now - there are some examples on how to use it server-side in the docs too.

An example (taken from the docs):

```js
// server example
// Running a gzip operation on every request is quite expensive.
// It would be much more efficient to cache the compressed buffer.
var zlib = require('zlib');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var raw = fs.createReadStream('index.html');
  var acceptEncoding = request.headers['accept-encoding'];
  if (!acceptEncoding) {
    acceptEncoding = '';
  }

  // Note: this is not a conformant accept-encoding parser.
  // See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3
  if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bdeflate\b/)) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'content-encoding': 'deflate' });
    raw.pipe(zlib.createDeflate()).pipe(response);
  } else if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bgzip\b/)) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'content-encoding': 'gzip' });
    raw.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(response);
  } else {
    response.writeHead(200, {});
    raw.pipe(response);
  }
}).listen(1337);
```

Comment: I ran into an issue with Internet Explorer not liking the zlib header which I resolved by using 'createDeflateRaw' instead of 'createDeflate'

Answer (score 66):

If you're using [Express](http://expressjs.com/), then you can use its compress method as part of the configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.compress());
```

And you can find more on compress here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#compress

And if you're not using [Express](http://expressjs.com/)... Why not, man?! :)

NOTE: (thanks to @ankitjaininfo) This middleware should be one of the first you "use" to ensure all responses are compressed. Ensure that this is above your routes and static handler (eg. how I have it above).

NOTE: (thanks to @ciro-costa) Since express 4.0, the `express.compress` middleware is deprecated.  It was inherited from connect 3.0 and express no longer includes connect 3.0.  Check [Express Compression](http://github.com/expressjs/compression) for getting the middleware.

Comment: Down vote without a comment?  Let me know why and hopefully I can improve the answer.  Or feel free to edit yourself.

Comment: `This middleware should be placed "high" within the stack to ensure all responses may be compressed. ` Ensure that this is above your routes and static handler

Comment: From now on `express.compress` middleware (which was inherited from connect 3.0<) is deprecated (since express 4.0) as it does not includes connect 3.0< anymore. Check https://github.com/expressjs/compression for getting the middleware.

Comment: to "Why not, man?!", the graphs on this page comparing raw http and express framework may give you a reason. express slows it down a bit https://raygun.io/blog/2015/02/node-js-performance-node-js-vs-io-js/

Comment: :) That was meant to be a bit tongue in cheek.  I actually don't love express, there are many more things I wish it did and much more polish I wish it had.  But it does well enough I suppose, until something else eclipses it.

Answer (score 48):

1- Install **compression**

```
npm install compression
```

2- Use it

```
var express     = require('express')
var compression = require('compression')

var app = express()
app.use(compression())
```

[compression on Github](https://github.com/expressjs/compression)

Comment: how to check whether static assest are gzip or not !

Comment: my images are not getting gzipped

Comment: actually you should this middleware when you are sending big JS/CSS files or big JSON files..  using this middleware won't give you benefit, instead it will consume more cpu resources. @JesonDias

Comment: @JesonDias you shouldn't gzip images because JPEG already includes a compression algo that works much better for images than gzip.  gzip is more for text based stuff.

Answer (score 38):

Generally speaking, for a production web application, you will want to put your node.js app behind a lightweight reverse proxy such as nginx or lighttpd. Among the many benefits of this setup, you can configure the reverse proxy to do http compression or even tls compression, without having to change your application source code.

Comment: don't let node serve static files, let the proxy take care of compression, find it to be best practice in prod-env, you might want to use nginx or lighty anyway to avoid your root usr running node on port 80

Comment: Depending on the usage, I'd really consider this to be the right answer.

Comment: @ezmilhouse Even if you have a proxy, your node.js server still has to *serve* those static files to the proxy, and there's no reason to waste bandwidth even in pipes inside the same machine.

Answer (score 10):

For compressing the file you can use below code

```
var fs = require("fs");
var zlib = require('zlib');
fs.createReadStream('input.txt').pipe(zlib.createGzip())
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('input.txt.gz'));
console.log("File Compressed.");
```

For decompressing the same file you can use below code

```
var fs = require("fs");
var zlib = require('zlib');
fs.createReadStream('input.txt.gz')
.pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('input.txt'));
console.log("File Decompressed.");
```

Comment: Would love to see some descriptional text in this answer! While your code snippets may answer the question, it is good practice to include some explanations for the TO and the rest of the world to understand _why_ it answers the question.

Answer (score 8):

Although you can gzip using a reverse proxy such as nginx, lighttpd or in varnish. It can be beneficial to have most http optimisations such as gzipping at the application level so that you can have a much granular approach on what asset's to gzip.

I have actually created my own gzip module for expressjs / connect called gzippo https://github.com/tomgco/gzippo although new it does do the job. Plus it uses node-compress instead of spawning the unix gzip command.

Comment: I'm using gzippo on a small node.js webserver now, good stuff!

Comment: how to check whether gzip is applied to static assests ?

Answer (score 6):

Even if you're not using express, you can still use their middleware. The [compression module](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) is what I'm using:

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')
var compress = require("compression")
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var noop = function(){}, useDefaultOptions = {}
  compress(useDefaultOptions)(request,response,noop) // mutates the response object

  response.writeHead(200)
  fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(response)
}).listen(1337)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Use gzip compression

Gzip compressing can greatly decrease the size of the response body and hence increase the speed of a web app. Use the compression middleware for gzip compression in your Express app. For example:

```
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.use(compression())
```

Comment: Do we need to decompress the response size at the client size?

Comment: @SiddharthSunchu No, it is transparently handled.

Answer (score 3):

While as others have right pointed out using a front end webserver such as `nginx` can handle this implicitly, another option, is to use [nodejitsu's](https://github.com/nodejitsu) excellent [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to serve up your assets.

eg:

```js
httpProxy.createServer(
 require('connect-gzip').gzip(),
 9000, 'localhost'
).listen(8000);
```

This example demonstrates support for gzip compression through the use of [connect middleware](https://github.com/nateps/connect-gzip) module: `connect-gzip`.

Answer (score 2):

How about [this](http://github.com/waveto/node-compress)?

> **node-compress**
>   A streaming compression / gzip module for node.js
>   To install, ensure that you have libz installed, and run:
>   node-waf configure
>   node-waf build
>   This will put the compress.node binary module in build/default.
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

As of today, `epxress.compress()` seems to be doing a brilliant job of this.

In any express app just call `this.use(express.compress());`.

I'm running locomotive on top of express personally and this is working beautifully. I can't speak to any other libraries or frameworks built on top of express but as long as they honor full stack transparency you should be fine.

Comment: This doesn't really have any new information, it duplicates this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14341423/1355166

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple Gzip middlewares for Express, KOA and others. For example:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip

However, Node is awfully bad at doing CPU intensive tasks like gzipping, SSL termination, etc. Instead, use a ‘real’ middleware services like nginx or HAproxy, see bullet 3 here:
http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practice-of-node-js-in-production/

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few good days with node, and you're right to say that you can't create a webserver without gzip.

There are quite a lot options given on the modules page on the Node.js Wiki. I tried out most of them, but this is the one which I'm finally using -

https://github.com/donnerjack13589/node.gzip

v1.0 is also out and it has been quite stable so far.

Comment: I think your comment is a bit misleading. While gzip is common in modern web applications, it's not a *necessity*. I think it's perfectly fine and standards compliant to not use it.