# nodejs compression doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, http-compression

I might be missing something, but I can't make my node server compress its static resources when responding.

this is how my relevant parts in the server look like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('ip', process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0");
// middlewares
app.use(express.compress({threshold : 0}));
```

a request for any static resource (js file for example) responses with un-compressed content and these are its headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
accept-ranges: bytes
etag: "7063-1409483577000"
date: Mon, 01 Sep 2014 07:26:33 GMT
cache-control: public, max-age=0
last-modified: Sun, 31 Aug 2014 11:12:57 GMT
content-type: application/javascript
content-length: 7063
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Could you tell us the version of express you're using : 3.x.x or 4.x.x ?

Comment: You can refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9238214/976897. As it mentions, compressing every request might be expensive. You should consider caching the compressed buffer.

Comment: I'm using express 3.4.8

Comment: I won't compress every request, I'm using the {threshold : 0} just to check whether the compression works or not.