# node.js: compressing strings

Tags: node.js, string, compression

I have a need to cache (in memory) a bunch of fairly lengthy strings.  Seems a shame to use memory unnecessarily, particularly when there is a memory quota imposed, so was wondering whether it's sensible to compress those strings before caching, and then decompress after fetching.

Seems like node.js has a built-in [zlib module](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html), and although that seems to be aimed more at file/stream compression, may be of use for simple string compression, e.g. from the docs:

```
var input = '.................................';
zlib.deflate(input, function(err, buffer) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(buffer.toString('base64'));
  }
});
```

Any thoughts?  Any other libraries or utility functions available?

Answer (score 1):

A question about nodejs compression, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894794/node-js-gzip-compression), led me to [this page](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/modules#compression), which lists a bunch of compression libraries.

I'm not sure of the exact context of your project, but if you are afraid that there may be issues regarding memory and performance it appears [that this library, called node-snappy](https://github.com/kesla/node-snappy) may be what you are looking for.

Basically, it takes a string like you want it to, and compresses it more efficiently than zlib, according to the author's benchmarks:

```
  snappy.compress() x 479 ops/sec ±0.99% (80 runs sampled)
  zlib.gzip() x 289 ops/sec ±1.66% (86 runs sampled)
  snappy.uncompress() x 652 ops/sec ±0.86% (43 runs sampled)
  zlib.gunzip() x 559 ops/sec ±1.65% (64 runs sampled)
```