# How to create Background VIdeo with cloudinary-react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

Any idea how i can create a Background Video (100vh, 100vw) using cloudinary-react?

Here is my Video Component:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { Video, CloudinaryContext, Transformation } from 'cloudinary-react'

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef()
  return (
    <CloudinaryContext cloud_name="joinshelf">
      <div className="h-screen w-screen">
        <Video publicId="luciana_e1vp7u" innerRef={videoRef}>
          <Transformation
            audioCodec="none"
            height="480"
            quality="auto"
            videoCodec="auto"
            width="852"
            crop="fill"
          />
        </Video>
      </div>
    </CloudinaryContext>
  )
}
export default VideoPlayer
```

If that not possible, any idea how to render a 11MB Video fast?
Right now it just a file in the public folder and im using Vercel for hosting

Thanks for the Helpers!

Comment: In the server, before sending a response you can zip the video file then download it to the client then unzip and use it.

Comment: How can I do it? do you have a recommended libarary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894794/node-js-gzip-compression

Comment: Yeah but it require backend code lol.

Comment: You will need to specify the vw in your CSS, something like https://css-tricks.com/full-page-background-video-styles/

Comment: server in the sense backend only.